# Can I Boot VMWare or Parallels from an internal OS X hard drive?

Tags: vmware, parallels-desktop

The SSD on my MacBook has 4 partitions, each of which has a bootable installation of **OS X**. Is there any way to boot from one of these partitions with a virtualization app? **I don't want to create an image from it**, just boot directly to the drive within an app.

It looks like Parallels and VMWare will only boot from images. I want to boot directly from the existing partition on my HD.

Comment: Parallels can boot a Windows Bootcamp partition. I don't know if it can do the same with other OS X partitions but I think it could, it would be similar to support.

Answer (score 1):

Parallels Desktop 8 can run Windows from a Boot Camp partition.

[Getting Started With Parallels Desktop (PDF)](http://www.parallels.com/fileadmin/parallels/documents/support/pd8fm/Getting_Started_With_Parallels_Desktop.pdf)

VMWare Fusion 5 can also run Windows from a Boot Camp partition.

[VMWare Fusion Overview](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html)

I believe Boot Camp support is available in earlier versions of both products, but it's definitely in the current shipping versions.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not interested in booting Windows, I want to boot *OS X*.